# Nginx client request max time

Tags: nginx

I have an Nginx web server that will proxy to some other servers behind, and when I test a file upload request by exercising a cap on the upload speed to modem like speed, I managed to hold the upload connection for at least 15 minutes. Is it possible to put a cap on the time for receiving client request body? I have tried client_body_timeout and a bunch of other directives but none of them seem to do the trick.

```
keepalive_timeout  65;

client_body_buffer_size 16k;
client_body_temp_path /var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body;
reset_timedout_connection on;
client_header_timeout 8;
client_body_timeout 60;
client_max_body_size 20M;
```

For the background info, I am thinking about Nginx equivalents of http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html

The HTTP connections are HTTP/1.1 keep-alive connections.

I am on Nginx 1.4.7 on Linux.

Comment: Why do you want that?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [proxy module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) and the set

```
proxy_read_timeout
```

to some sane value.

Comment: Thank you tex. However, isn't it that only until the request is fully buffered by Nginx that it will begin forwarding to backend server? I put it in a tcpdump and could not find any traffic between Nginx and backend server while the slow upload is still proceeding. Thanks.